# Can't certificate PDF file with TCPDF

Tags: laravel, certificate, digital-signature, tcpdf

I want to certificate a PDF File with Laravel and sign it with two signatures (one of the employee and one of the recruiter). I tried TCPDF Library with slef-signed certificate (generated with openssl) but the pdf generated was not certified, also I can't add image in pdf, an error was occured : `TCPDF ERROR: TCPDF requires the Imagick or GD extension to handle PNG images with alpha channel.`  I try to solve it with adding Imagick to xampp but it's not solved .

Any suggestions to certifcate the pdf and sign it with multiple signatures !?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add to your php.ini file this extensions.

```
extension=php_imagick.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Unix

```
extension=imagick.so
```

Comment: I've already add them but nothing change

Comment: If `php -m` in console